# What is the RSA SecurID packet format?

Tags: wireshark, rsa

I am testing a client application that authenticates using RSA SecurID hardware tokens. The authentication is failing and I am not finding any useful information in the log files.

I am using Authentication Manager 8.0 and the Java SDK.

I have a traffic capture which I would like to analyze with Wireshark to and from port 5500 on the authentication agent. But I can't find the packet format searching the internet or on the the RSA SecurCare knowledge base.

Can anybody direct me to the packet format?

Here is an extract from the rsa_api_debug.log file which dumps the UDP payload of the request and the response:

```
[2013-11-06 15:11:08,602] main - b.a():? - Sending 508 bytes to 192.168.10.121; contents: 
5c 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 ea 71 ee 50 6e 45 83 95 8 39 4 72 e 55 cf cc 62 6d d5 a4 10 79 89 13 d5 23 6a c1 ab 33 8 c3 a1 91 92 93 4f 1e 4 8d 2a 22 2c d0 c3 7 fc 96 5f ba bf 0 80 60 60 9d 1d 9c b9 f3 58 4b 43 18 5f e0 6d 5e f5 f4 5d df bf 41 b9 9 ae 46 a0 a9 66 2d c7 6 f6 d7 66 f1 4 f8 ad 8a 9f 4d 7e e5 9c 45 67 16 15 33 70 f0 1 d5 c0 38 39 f5 fd 5e 15 4f e3 fe ea 70 fa 30 c9 e0 18 ab 64 a9 fe 2c 89 78 a2 96 b6 76 3e 2e a2 ae 2e e0 69 80 8d 51 9 56 80 f4 1a 73 9a 70 f3 e7 c1 49 49 c3 41 3 c6 ce 3e a8 68 71 3f 2 b2 9b 27 8e 63 ce 59 38 64 d1 75 b7 b7 1f 62 eb 4d 1d de c7 21 e0 67 85 b e6 c3 80 0 60 54 47 e ef 3 f9 33 7b 78 e2 3e db e4 8e 76 73 45 3 38 34 1e dd 43 3e 72 a7 37 72 5 34 8e f4 ba 9d 71 6c e 45 49 fa 92 a f6 b bf 5 b 4f dc bd 19 0 7e d2 ef 94 d 3b 78 17 37 d9 ae 19 3a 7e 46 7d ea e4 3a 8c e1 e5 9 50 a2 eb df f2 57 97 bc f2 c3 a7 6f 19 7f 2c 1a 3f 94 25 19 4b b2 37 ed ce 97 f ae f ec c9 f5 be f0 8f 72 1c 34 84 1b 11 25 dd 44 8b 99 75 a4 77 3d e1 1d 26 41 58 55 5f d5 27 82 c d3 2a f8 4 aa 8d 5e e4 79 0 49 43 59 27 5e 15 87 a f4 c4 57 b6 e1 f8 79 3b d3 20 69 5e d0 80 6a 6b 9f 43 79 84 94 d0 77 b6 fc f 3 22 ca b9 35 c0 e8 7b e9 25 26 7f c9 fb e4 a7 fc bb b7 75 ac 7b bc f4 bb 4f a8 80 9b 73 da 3 94 da 87 e7 94 4c 80 b3 f1 2e 5b d8 2 65 25 bb 92 f4 92 e3 de 8 ee 2 30 df 84 a4 69 a6 a1 d0 9c e7 8e f 8 71 4b d0 1c 14 ac 7c c6 e3 2a 2e 2a c2 32 bc 21 c4 2f 4d df 9a f3 10 3e e5 c5 7f ad e4 fb ae 99 bf 58 0 20 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
[2013-11-06 15:11:08,602] main - b.b():? - Enterring getResponse
[2013-11-06 15:11:08,618] main - b.a():? - Enterring getTimeoutValue(AceRequest AceAuthV4Request[AbstractAceRequest[ hdr=AcePacketHeader[Type=92 Ver=5 AppID=3 Enc=ENCRYPT Hi-Proto=5 Opt=0 CirID=0] created=1383750668571 trailer=AcePackeTrailer[nonce=39e7a607b517c4dd crc=722833884]] user=bmatthews                                                        node-sec-req=0 wpcodes=null resp-mac=0 m-resp-mac=0 client=192.168.10.3 passcode==ZTmY|?        sec-sgmt=AceSecondarySegments[ cnt=3] response=none])
[2013-11-06 15:11:08,618] main - b.a():? - acm base timeout: 5
[2013-11-06 15:11:08,618] main - b.b():? - Timeout is 5000
[2013-11-06 15:11:08,618] main - b.b():? - Current retries: 0
[2013-11-06 15:11:10,618] main - b.b():? - Received 508 bytes from 192.168.10.121; contents:
6c 5 0 3 3 6 0 0 0 0 0 1 4d 18 55 ca 18 df 84 49 70 ee 24 4a a5 c3 1c 4e 36 d8 51 ad c7 ef 49 89 6e 2e 23 b4 7e 49 73 4 15 d f4 d5 c0 bf fc 72 5b be d1 62 be e0 de 23 56 bf 26 36 7f b f0 ba 42 61 9b 6f 4b 96 88 9c e9 86 df c6 82 e5 4c 36 ee dc 1e d8 a1 0 71 65 89 dc ca ee 87 ae d6 60 c 86 1c e8 ef 9f d9 b9 4c ed 7 55 77 f3 fc 92 61 f9 32 70 6f 32 67 4d fc 17 4e 7b eb c3 c7 8c 64 3f d0 d0 c7 86 ad 4e 21 41 a2 80 dd 35 ba 31 51 e2 a0 ef df 82 52 d0 a8 43 cb 7c 51 c 85 4 c5 b2 ec 8f db e1 21 90 f5 d7 1b d7 14 ca c0 40 c5 41 4e 92 ee 3 ec 57 7 10 45 f3 54 d7 e4 e6 6e 79 89 9a 21 70 7a 3f 20 ab af 68 34 21 b7 1b 25 e1 ab d 9f cd 25 58 5a 59 b1 b8 98 58 2f 79 aa 8a 69 b9 4c c1 7d 36 28 a3 23 f5 cc 2b ab 9e f a1 79 ab 90 fd 5f 76 9f d9 86 d1 fc 4c 7a 4 24 6d de 64 f1 53 22 b0 b7 91 9a 7c a2 67 2a 35 68 83 74 6a 21 ac eb f8 a2 29 53 21 2f 5a 42 d6 26 b8 f6 7f 79 96 5 3b c2 15 3a b d0 46 42 b7 74 4e 1f 6a ad f5 73 70 46 d3 f8 e a3 83 a3 15 29 6e 68 2 df 56 5c 88 8d 6c 2f ab 11 f1 5 73 58 ec 4 5f 80 e3 ca 56 ce 8 b9 73 7c 79 fc 3 ff f1 40 97 bb e3 fb 35 d1 8d ba 23 fc 2d 27 5b f7 be 15 de 72 30 b e d6 5c 98 e8 44 bd ed a4 3d 87 b8 9b 35 e9 64 80 9a 2a 3c a2 cf 3e 39 cb f6 a2 f4 46 c7 92 99 bc f7 4a de 7e 79 9d 9b d9 34 7f df 27 62 4f 5b ef 3a 4c 8d 2e 66 11 f7 8 c3 84 6e 57 ba 2a 76 59 58 78 41 18 66 76 fd 9d cb a2 14 49 e1 59 4a 6e f5 c3 94 ae 1a ba 51 fc 29 54 ba 6c 95 57 6b 20 87 cc b8 dc 5f 48 72 9c c0 2c dd 60 56 4e 4c 6c 1d 40 bd 4 a1 10 4e a4 b1 87 83 dd 1c f2 df 4c 
[2013-11-06 15:11:10,618] main - a.a():? - Response status is: 1
[2013-11-06 15:11:10,618] main - a.a():? - Authenticaton failed for bmatthews !
[2013-11-06 15:11:10,618] main - AuthSessionFactory.shutdown():? - RSA Authentication API shutdown invoked
[2013-11-06 15:11:10,618] main - AuthSessionFactory.shutdown():? - RSA Authentication API  shutdown successful
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that while RSA info can come into your network in a number of ways (usually over HTTP), the actual authentication happens on a RADIUS server using the AAA protocol.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS#Packet_structure

Comment: The SDK I am using is talking to the Authentication Agent. I think the agent may in turn be making the RADIUS request. But that is not what is passing between the SDK and Authentication Agent. I pasted an extra ct from one of the which dumps the UDP packet payload.